# Different Results for Double Pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, oscillators

In this [study](https://www.csaapt.org/uploads/3/4/4/2/34425343/csaapt_maypalace_sp16.pdf), (Hidden Fractals in the Dynamics of the Compound Double Pendulum) the authors provide various fliptime fractals (of a double pendulum) for different length combinations. However, when I tried to replicate their results, the shapes (for $3l_1 = l_2$ in particular) did not match up. I used a fourth order Runge Kutta with adaptive step size and a max-step of 0.01 or 0.05 and simulated the pendulum for 100 seconds. Here are my results.

[image: l_1 = l_2]
[image: 2l_1 = l_2]
[image: 3l_1 = l_2]

$l_1 = l_2$, $2l_1 = l_2$, and $3l_1 = l_2$
However, the article provides this image for $3l_1 = l_2$:
[image: article image]

My $2l_1 = l_2$ and the article's $3_l1 = l_2$ resembles a square-ish shape. My $2l_1$ and $3l_1$ do not match the article, only $l_1 = l_2$ bares a similar resemblance. The article does not include a $2l_1 = l_2$ image.

Which image is right? I find it fishy that my $2_l1$ resembles their $3_l1$. Thanks :)

(some other parameters: masses are equal, gravity is 9.81, used solve_ivp() from scipy. I am happy to provide more if needed)

Comment: I don't know that anyone could diagnose where yours went wrong/different than a published paper without seeing the code. But seeing how [we don't debug code](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-physics/info), it's likely this will be closed. You may want to try [scicomp.se] where such questions should be on topic.

Comment: I think it’s fair to say that you most definitely simulated $l_2=3l_1$ by accident when you set $l_2=2l_1$. Double check the equations of motion. It’s easier if you write things in dimensionless variables, normally, you should only have one parameter: $l_2/l_1$.